# Is there a logo for working without javascript and/or cookies?

Tags: cookies, usability, privacy

I am more inclined to continue using a content-driven site like a news outlet or blog if it functions properly without javascript or cookies.

Are there any logos or other visual indicators for a website-owner to say "I am proud to function without javascript!" and "Reject unnecessary cookies!"?

Comment: It's clear that you care about web sites which function without JavaScript or cookies. The question is - how many of your potential audience actually care?

Comment: The no-script logo maybe?

Comment: Most people don't know that it's something you *could* care about.  This is all the more reason to make it visible.

Comment: How will you explain it to them?

Comment: Explaining the nuances isn't a goal and is better left for others.  If I went to a site and saw it had a logo on it that said "Banana-free", there's an off-chance I'd try to find out what web-bananas are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider borrowing from established related logos.  Two I can think of are DuckDuckGo's [Don't Track Us](http://donttrack.us/) campaign and [NoScript](http://noscript.net).  A badge showing that you support the [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://eff.org) would also go pretty far to help assure users that you care about these things.

Examples:

[image: don't track us]
[image: noscript]
[image: join EFF]

Markdown doesn't let me fully demonstrate what I'm talking about, but I'd put text below each badge that talks about why you're including it; below donttrack.us, you can say "no cookies, no tracking," below noscript, "no javascript," and below EFF, "we support online privacy."  (Or, if you do have cookies and/or JS, you can say something else, maybe "noscript friendly" for JS.)

If you have an SSL version of your page, you can also put an SSL padlock badge (ideally *only* on that version of the page).

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**

[image]

---

Since there is no sign of any *movement* or *iniciative* on the interwebs that would support your case, it seems to be necessary, as @savanto suggests, to start your own.

Some points I would suggest follow.

- I would suggest something with padlock on it. [Anything with padlock on it makes the user feel secure](http://www.westpoint.ltd.uk/papers/ssl-paved-with-good-intentions.pdf).
- I would suggest something positive - "I love security" is much more *in* now than "I hate haxx0rz".
- I would suggest you write briefly and concisely [what](http://agilemanifesto.org/) and why and putting it on your website - you may as well write history and do a good job advertising your blog, since there may be others with the same attitude yet nobody posted a blog on this topic so far.
- I would suggest you make the logo as green as possible, since green is a friendly colour and may suggest, among other, that not transmitting unnecessary javascript and cookies you and your visitors do a tiny bit of good for our mother earth.
- I would suggest you dedicate the logo and the explanation to public domain.

I hereby dedicate the above posted logo to the public domain. Feel free to use it and do whatever you find sound with it.

Comment: A padlock implies encryption.  Do not use a padlock if you aren't encrypted, especially if you don't even offer proper encryption.

Comment: @AdamKatz I daresay it doesn't: for people who do know what encryption _is_ any symbol of padlock doesn't mean anything at all, and to the others, it just brings the [warm fuzzy feeling](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/be-consultant.html). Altough it may not be totally in line with the unsaid guidelines about website padlocking, it needs to address _both_ target groups - those who know what javascript and cookies are as well as those who only understand little padlock icons :)

Comment: I love that you created a logo and surrendered it to public domain; I'm selecting @AdamKatz answer because I agree regarding the use of padlocks in the absence of encryption, and I hadn't seen the Don't Track Us campaign.

Comment: Looks like I need to rethink my padlock view :-) The Don't Track Us is new to me as well and sure _the_ valid answer to your question. I have on _but_ for you, if you please: just don't use the _No Script_ snake badge - it does the whole Interwebs a huge disfavour.